# How to pass variables to function as a vector?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I want to use 3 variables in the form of a vector inside a function, for example the variables: L (length), B (breadth), H (height)

Instead of the usual case:

```
volume <- function(D,B,H) {
  vol <- H - ((5*7.2*B) / 1.7*D)
  return(vol)
}

volume(7,8,9)
```

I want to pass `x = c(D,B,H)`, a vector consisting variables D,B,H:

```
volume <- function(x) {
  x <- c(D,B,H) # This is incorrect 
  vol <- H - ((5*7.2*B) / 1.7*D)
  return(vol)
}

H <- 7
B <- 8
D <- 1
volume(x)
```

and when I call the function will take some input values as shown above and return a value for volume.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: alright is something like,
vol <- H-((5*7.2*B) / 1.7*D)
Something like this, its not just a product

Comment: Your question is unclear. Maybe the answer is `vol <- x[[1]] * x[[2]] * x[[3]]`, or the answer is `do.call(somefunction, as.list(x))`.

Comment: Yep Thanks heaps :)
This is kinda what I was looking for. But maybe in the form of a vector

Comment: Your question's unclear. If you merely want to syntactically package your function args so your function body can refer to them as `D,B,H`, then either use a **named list**, or else pass in a vector, and **unpack it by indexing into the vector `D <- x[[1]]; B <- x[[2]]; H <- x[[3]];`**. R does not do tuple-unpacking like Python, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a named list :

```
volume <- function(x) {
  vol <- x$H-((5*7.2*x$B) / 1.7*x$D)
  return(vol)
}

H <- 7
B <- 8
D <- 1
volume(list(H = H, B = B, D = D))
[1] -162.4118
```

Comment: Thanks, but the actual equation I am trying to solve isn't  just multiplication. What I am interested in is:
volume <- function(x)
where x is a vector that represent 3 variables (i.e Height, width & breadth)

Comment: @user727 please have a look at my updated answer